# Как получить список отложенных задач из всего проекта в одном файле

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Не знаю есть ли вообще такой механизм, но хотелось бы, чтобы каким-то образом мне в одном месте выводились все комментарии со ссылками на файлы, в которых эти комментарии были приписаны.

Т. е. я оставляю в проекте в разных местах комментарии для самого себя или для кого-нибудь, в которых бы говорилось, что тут что-то нужно доделать, или я хочу что-то тут сделать в будущем.

В итоге это позволит мне не рыться по всем файлам и не вспоминать, что 3 недели назад я когда-то в одном месте оставил комент, но забыл где и что там было написано. Чтобы я на следующий день мог открыть проект и в отдельном месте просмотреть все те задачи, которые я планировал сделать с указанием места, где эти задачи хотелось бы сделать и т.п. или указания о том, что я где-то что-то не доделал. Это даст возможность видеть такие задачи и решать их в первую очередь.

Возможно кому-то такая "система" не нужна и покажется бессмысленной, но для меня, человека, который выполняет полный стек операций по созданию приложения для Android (его дизайн (работа в фотошопе), далее декстопное приложение для него и программирование микроконтроллера), было бы очень удобно иметь под рукой такой инструмент, чтобы не тратить время только на то, чтобы вспомнить все те задачи, которые я поставил себе ранее.

Тупо записывать задачи в блокноте не практично, хотелось бы просто оставлять комменты и в отдельном файле получать весь список, а по нажатии на элемент переходить к строчке в коде с этим коментом.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Пишите комментарии в таком виде (начиная с TODO):

```
//Todo: Надо ещё сделать вот это и вон то
```

Потом ищите вкладку TODO в левом-нижнем углу:

[image: Вкладка TODO]

Там они все должны появиться.

[image: screen2]

**UPDATE:**

помимо тега *todo* - сделать , можно использовать еще тег *fixme* - исправить.
 Комментарии, начинающиеся с *fixme* отображаются в той же вкладке TODO и отличаются от *todo* только смысловой нагрузкой:

```
//fixme Не работает на API21
```

Comment: ДА, это оно, то что хотел, вы просто мастер, сэкономили мне тонну времени, Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, а если безотносительно android-studio, то [emacs + grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) легко решают такие проблемы

Comment: Спасибо и вам, на данный момент мне хватит и того, что описано выше, но ваш метод тоже осмотрю

Comment: @avp Как в связке  emacs + grep  насчет перехода к месту TODO-заметки из выборки grep? В AS из списка TODO можно сразу перейти к месту, где оставлена TODO-заметка, что, согласитесь, удобно.

Comment: @pavlofff, да, в окошке \*grep\* надо щелкать мышкой по строчке в списке результатов, чтобы в другом появился нужный файл (позиционируется в нужное место в нем).